# Check if images are opened and get details of each image from ImagePlus instance

Tags: java, imagej

I'm working on writing plugins for ImageJ. I need help on how to check if an image is opened or not. For current opened image, I have imagePlus instance. But the methods inside the imageplus doesn't seem like giving any details about opened/active images. Below is the current code I'm using to show images, but I'm not sure how to check if the images are opened or not.

```
Opener imagejOpener = new Opener();
String imageFilePath = path;
ImagePlus imagePlus = imagejOpener.openImage(imageFilePath);
imagePlus.show();
```

Do we have any static classes or methods which can just check WindowManager or something to decide if any images are opened or not.

Comment: What do you mean by 'open images'?

Comment: I mean, I want to check if we have any images opened in Imagej already. Images can be opened in any way, either like file->open or else programmatically which I showed you above `imagejopener.openImage();`.

Comment: If you open and close images programatically, why don't you programatically store information about which images are currently opened, like singleton holding list of paths ?

Comment: Yeah, thats fine in case if user opens files using my plugin and then edits it. But, I also have few cases where user may open files using 1st option (file->open). In such case, my plugin has to detect opened images(if any) and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [javadoc of the `ij.WindowManager`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/WindowManager.html) class. It has the following static methods that might be useful to you:

> `static int  getImageCount()` Returns the number of open images.
>
> `static int  getWindowCount()` Returns the number of open image windows.
>
> `static int[]  getIDList()` Returns a list of the IDs of open images.

and to get the current image as an `ImagePlus` instance:

> `static ImagePlus  getCurrentImage()`

When writing plugins, you should better use:

```
import IJ;
ImagePlus imp = IJ.getImage();
```

See also the [`ij.IJ`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/IJ.html) helper class.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping on time. As suggested, static methods if IJ class actually helped me. I pulled imagePlus instance `IJ.getImage()` of current image and then got further details about it by using `imp.getTitle` and relative methods.

Comment: I also tried using WindowManager, but it looks like it didn't work in my case. I'm not sure why. Static methods `WindowManager.getImage()` and `WindowManager.getImageCount()`of WindowManager gave me `null` all the time.